# What is meant by "put the file in your path"

Tags: bashrc, conky, configure

I am little confused about an instruction I came across. It stated "put the file in your path". I interpreted that as to add

```
PATH=$PATH:'~/.conkystart'
```

to my `~/.bashrc`. The file is `~/.conkystart`

```
#!/bin/bash
conky -c ~/.conkyrc2
```

and `~/.conkyrc2` is a second conky fig file.

However, when I restarted, the second conkyrc file didn't execute and there were no errors in the bash terminal. Am I interpreting "put the file in your path" incorrectly? If so, what should I have done instead?

The end game is for `~/.conkyrc2` to execute on boot.

Comment: Your interpretation is incorrect, since `PATH` is a list of directories. You should copy/move/link it to a directory that is present in PATH, or add the directory containing it to PATH. That said, I don't see why adding it to PATH should cause it execute automatically. What is it you're trying to do and what instructions are you following?

Comment: @muru I want `~/.conkyrc2` to execute on boot.

Comment: Just add it to Startup Applications

Comment: @OrganicMarble I actually dont use Ubuntu. I was just asking this here as a general linux question.

Comment: You do not want to run that at boot as X is not running yet and you will get an error message. You want it to run when you log in. It is more likely you want to start conky at login as I am going to guess conkyrc2 is not a script (although it could be).

Comment: As @bodhi.zazen says, do it at login.  In Ubuntu the straightforward way is to just put conky in Startup Applications with a short delay to ensure the desktop has started.  But if you are not an Ubuntu user....

Answer (score 2):

To add a file to your PATH, first find out what PATH is with:

```
echo $PATH
```

Then, move the file to one of those directories.

Comment: Will this have the file execute on boot as well?

Comment: No, it will not.